# run a linux script on an event in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, text, editor

i have been making a text writer where u can create a file and then u can also store it into a folder of d web server, like wase a cloud computing system.

but i have a prob that how to save the file when the menu is clicked. i am trying it with exec() function of php, to run a scritp but not getting how to invoke the script on click event. plz hepl out, ur input will be highly appriciated.

and also is there option to open a saved file on click into the text writer dynamically.

thanks!!

Comment: I understand you might not know English well enough, but hey, don't try making it harder for us by using mnemonics...

Comment: sorry sir, i just made this mistake, but never the less, please try to help me out

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just save it with `fwrite()` function?

I mean, it's a usual method of saving files – `fopen()` it for writing, `fwrite()` data and finally `fclose()` the file. You either use general approach or tell us more about your specific needs.

If you still need to run unix/linux commands from PHP, the option to debug what's happening is to log in to command line as a user PHP is running under – e.g. *www-data* or *nobody*. You can find it out by running this in your script (see [the backtick execution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)):

```
print `whoami`;
```

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try, i think it will work on windows system also